# Find the kernel and range of the following transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

If the given transformation is
$$T(\begin{bmatrix}V_1 \\ V_2 \\ V_3\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}V_1 \\V_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Find the column space and null space for the given transformation

Comment: Isn't it range of the transformation?

Comment: Please use Latex while asking any questions on this platform. It provides extra readability.   Here is a [short tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Before seeing the answer, please see this [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZoltpSPTA7W-8_1iNObIy79mRW65KiV/view?usp=sharing).
Given,
$$
T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
v_3\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
Calculating nullspace is easy.
$$
T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
k\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore $Nullspace(T) = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

To get the column space or range we need to find the matrix behind this transformation. We gonna look at what $T$ does to each basis vector.
$$
T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore the matrix looks like $T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Above $T$ is already is in reduced row-echelon form. Therefore
$$
Col(T) = span\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}
$$